# How were the absolute masses of atoms calculated before the mass spectrometers?

Tags: atoms, mass-spectrometry, history-of-chemistry, protons

I understand that true (non-relative) masses of atoms are calculated with a mass spectrometer. using this relationship: Centripetal Force = Force due to magnetic field(B)

But I was wondering how masses of atoms were calculated before the mass spectrometers were invented.

(Please don't get this mixed up with relative atomic mass. That's not what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 6):

Absolute mass can be determined electrochemically, once the *coulomb* is defined in terms of numbers of electrons, as through the Millikan oil-drop experiment, to be  $6.24×10^{18}$ electrons per coulomb.

See [Determination of Avogadro's Number](http://www.if.ufrj.br/~moriconi/termo_fisest/avogadro.htm) and [Absolute  Determination  of  the  Electrochemical  Equivalent and  the  Atomic  Weight  of Zinc](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/79A/jresv79An6p747_A1b.pdf).

One thing that caused confusion in the determination of atomic mass is natural isotopic separation, e.g. sulfur derived from condensation from vulcanism vs. from mineral compounds, so that there were slightly different experimental results depending on source.